# Numerical Solution for a specified parameter in NDSolve (Mathematica)

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, bioinformatics, pde

I am working on a solution to solve a Partial Differential Equation, Fick's Second Law of Diffusion to be exact.
I was able to produce a 3D Plot using the NDSolve and Plot3D functions. 
Code used:

```
NDSolve[{D[c[t, h], t] == 1*D[c[t, h], h, h],
               c[0, h] == Erfc[h/(2*81.2)], 
               c[t, 0] == 1, 
            c[t, 4000] == 3.08*^-18}, c, {t, 0, 900}, {h, 0, 274}]
```

Instead of a graphical representation, I would like to find numerical points of the graph at t = 900.
I would like to know how to put in t = 900 into NDSolve (or other functions) so as to generate detailed numerical points of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the solution in a variable first:

```
e = NDSolve[{D[c[t, h], t] == 1*D[c[t, h], h, h], c[0, h] == Erfc[h/(2*81.2)], c[t, 0] == 1, c[t, 4000] == 3.08*^-18}, c, {t, 0, 900}, {h, 0, 274}]
```

Then we can Evaluate this expression for our desired variables:

```
Evaluate[c[900, 10] /. e]
(*{0.914014}*)
```

Or to make it more versatile, we can use Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[Evaluate[c[t, h] /. e], {t, 0, 900}, {h, 0, 274}]
```

[image: Manipulate]

**Update:**
Considering the information I received from the comments below; we can define a function like *q[t,h]* which will give us the solution as a function:

```
q[t_, h_] := Evaluate[c[t, h] /. e]
q[900, 10]
(*{0.914014}*)
```

Comment: A tad neater, since we know there is one solution define `e = c /. First@NDSolve..` then you can directly use e as : `e[900,10] -> .91`

Comment: Thank you very much George!! That is exactly what I was trying to do !
But I can't seem to define e = c /. First@NDSolve..
I got an error message: 
First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[NDSolve]. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {First[NDSolve]..} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to put the whole expression `First@NDsolve[ equations , vars, etc ]` too long to type in a comment..